# AE Expression to increment slider value (on text layer) whenever a frame lands on a marker?

Tags: slider, expression, after-effects

I am completely new to AE expressions.

Suppose that I have bunch of layer markers on a text layer, and the text is linked to a slider control:

[image]

Now, what I want is that whenever the playhead (or the current frame) lands on the next marker(s), I want the slider to increment by 1, like this:

[image]

I want an expression which I can add to the Slider to achieve the desired result. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I posted this question on Reddit as well, they told me to use ChatGPT. I tried using it, but it doesn't achieve the desired result after trying several different prompts and even when breaking down the problem into parts.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, I got rid of the slider, added a "Numbers" effect to the text layer (which displays the counter), and added the following expression code to the "Value/..." property:

```
for (i = 1; i <= thisLayer.marker.numKeys; i++) {
    if (thisLayer.marker.key(i).time <= time) {
        value = value + 1;
    }
    else {
        value;
    }
}
```